# IPOPT in Pyomo does not work from source only with executable

Tags: python, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I have a complicated non-linear problem I cannot copy here, where I have used IPOPT.exe so far (v 3.9.1) in a pyomo environment without a problem. Lately I experienced that the value of the objective function highly varies based on the settings:

- if I decrease the tolerance the value gets more accurate at first (for some digits), but then it jumps to another value, which is 10% bigger than the previous
- my optimization problem is the same for every run, except the value of one parameter (the hour I am evaluating the function in), still IPOPT can sometimes find the solution in 2 sec, sometimes I get infeasible result or max iteration reached (the parameter change is in a range that should not cause any anomaly in the system)
- since it is a nasty problem I expected that ipopt randomly "jumps into" the problem, but it is not the case, it returns the same exit and value even if trying the problem several times (with for attempt: - try: - etc.).
- also the result is different depending on if I use "exact" or "limited memory" hessian approximation.
- since I do not like this behavior I wanted to use the multistart option but I cannot define an "executable" path with the option so I figured I change from the executable file to an installed solver.
- I installed cyipopt and the ipopt to have everything and it works fine with another sample example but does not on my problem. It returns: ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (3221225501) without any feedback. I cannot figure out the cause.

So the questions would be:

- how do I know which options to set and which is its proper value?
- why do I keep always getting the same result even if I start the process completely new?
- can I define an executable with the multistart option? and will it change anything or I should focus more on initializing the variables to a better value?
- which is the easiest way to foster convergence?

I know it is not one issue but they belong together in the same context. Thanks for the answers in advance!

Comment: This sounds very very broad and i'm sceptical if there is much help here. 1+2 sound like numerical-trouble. As pyomo probably does automatic-differentiation (numerical-diff not the culprit), it's probably due to *scaling*. 3 sounds like what i would expect from the solver (in general): *determinism*. There will be a initial-point procedure (like in all IPMs) and i hope it's not random. In general you might be able to supply initial-points somehow although this might be tough for IPMs. 4. Normal behaviour; strengthened by numerical-difficulties. 5 What? 6 Without code impossible to debug.

Comment: Thanks sascha, big help already. Im comfortable with the formulation of the physical model but I am lost in such a mathematical formulation which can be solved. 
- indeed, I have multiple variables in different scalse(e.g. -30<X1<15, 0<X2<infinite) could you recommend a good scaling practice with unbound or negative values?
-5: so far I am using the SolverFactory('ipopt', executable = C:\etc.) function with an exe file. It works with that. After installing IPOPT with conda and trying SolverFactory('ipopt'), I get the message I mentioned.

Comment: The problem may be non-convex. The solver will go to a different local optimum depending on the details. Also, Pyomo supports different NLP solvers. It often helps to try out a few.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Erwin. Could you suggest any? I spent considerable time on searching for open-source NLP solvers but I have not found any other than IPOPT. Thanks in advance!